# Coordinate of the end of arc in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to calculate the coordinate of the end of an arc in tikz but there seems to be an error I couldn't fix. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6, >=latex']
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[anchor=north] {$x$};
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(-1.5,3.5);
\draw[Honeydew4,thick] (-1.5, 0) arc (180:160:3);
\fill [red] ($(-1.5,0) + (-3*cos(20),sin(20))$)  circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just name it so you can refer to it again e.g. `... arc (180:160:3) coordinate (some name);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to just give the coordinate a name so you can refer to it:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6, >=latex']
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[anchor=north] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(-1.5,3.5);
    \draw[Honeydew4,thick] (-1.5, 0) arc (180:160:3) coordinate (c);
    \fill [red] (c) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: naming a coordinate for later use]